# Video uploading server issues in android

Tags: android, server

I want to upload video upto 30 mb on the server but the the server which I am using on that video with size more than 2 mb can't be uploaded. I had tried on other server there it work. Is there any server limitations? server which I am using have 30GB space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

increasing upload size limit will solve the problem.